# Invoice template: render html table "Discount" column only if any item has a discount

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Disclaimer, I haven't worked with Django or Python before, so any help/guidance is appreciated.

I'm working on a quote/invoice template using Jinja/Django syntax. A quote has multiple line items, some of which may have a discount on them. I'd only like to render the "Discount" column in the html table if any one of the items has a discount on it.

**The trouble I am having is figuring out if any one item has a discount (either dollar or percent), and telling the template to render or not render that html conditionally as a result.**

This is a simplified array/list of line item data available:

```
lineItems=[
{acv=64000.0
discount=
discount_percentage=
price=64000
quantity=1
name=Item One
id=0}

{acv=44000.0
discount=1500
discount_percentage=
price=44000
quantity=1
name=Item One
id=1}

{acv=2000.0
discount=
discount_percentage=
price=2000
quantity=1
name=Item One
id=2}
]
```

At first I thought to create a global "hasItemDiscount" variable, and then use a `for` loop to iterate through the list items and update the global variable if any had a discount value than 0.

Something to this effect:

```
{% set hasItemDiscount = false %}
{% for item in lineItems %}
  {% if item.discount > 0 or item.discount_percentage > 0 %}
  {% set hasItemDiscount = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% if hasItemDiscount == true %}
<th scope="col">DISCOUNT</th>
{% endif %}
```

But, I realized it is not possible to update a global variable from the local context of the loop. Nor is it apparently a good idea to create a global variable.

*Note: I'll also add that I have to use a > operator or similar because there is a small issue with the system where if a discount is applied to an item and then removed, the attribute in the data still exists but is empty, ex `discount=`.*

---

Ultimately two things need to be conditionally rendered in the html table: 1) the table header "Discount", and 2) if any one item has a discount, the extra table cell for discount needs to render on all line items even if they don't have one so that the table structure doesn't break.

If no item in the list has a discount, neither the table heading or the associated cells in the column should render.

Hopefully this was clear enough!

Comment: I have no experience with jinja2, but, when using django's own template engine, I would do this calculation in python code and just pass the result to the template as a context variable.

Comment: @SMoenig i'll have to check if i'm able to write python in the template files.

Comment: i meant doing the calculation in the view, before template rendering starts.